# Strange behavior of dropdownlist selected values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am populating a DDL with another DDL and i am getting the value from another page`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry();
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select country--");

    }


    if(Session["uname"]!=null)
    {
          DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session["country"].ToString();
       ProfileMasterBLL bll=new ProfileMasterBLL();
        foreach (var VARIABLE in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry())
        {
            if (VARIABLE.ToString().Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
            {
                var query = (ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountrys(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
                DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
             }
        }




        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));

      DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text).Selected = true;
        string str = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

        DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text).Selected = true;

      var states = (new ProfileMasterDAL()).GetStatesByCountry(str);
      DropDownList2.Enabled = true;
        DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
        DropDownList2.DataSource = states;
        DropDownList2.DataBind();

    }



  <countrys>
  <country>
    <name>India</name>
    <state>
      <text>Maharashtra</text>
      <text>Kashmir</text>
      <text>Goa</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name>Sri lanka</name>
    <state>
      <text>Kanady</text>
      <text>Colombo</text>
      <text>Galle</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name> Australia</name>
    <state>
      <text>Sydney</text>
      <text>Perth</text>
      <text>Melbourne</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name>South Africa</name>
    <state>
      <text>Capetown</text>
      <text>Johanusburg</text>
      <text>Durban</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name>USA</name>
    <state>
      <text>Alabama</text>
      <text>California</text>
      <text>Detroit</text>
    </state>
  </country>
  <country>
    <name>UK</name>
    <state>
      <text>London</text>
      <text>Paris</text>
      <text>Italy</text>
    </state>
  </country>
</countrys>
```

The weird problem is that if i select the DDL to some other country say UK or USA the DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text value remains south africa(the value from the session) and if i select the countries above south africa states DDL is populating i dont what is the reason behind it?any solution or suggestions for it?

```
f (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select a country--");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because you rebind your DDL every time, you must just one time whane

```
if(! IsPostBack)
{
   //Just one time here

}
```

And you persist your DDL with Viewstate

You can add Chandra `AutoPostBack="true"` on your DDL, and add OnSelectChanged on your DDL

In your data base verify that your states are mapped to the good name of country

For example DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "USA"

```
var query = (ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountrys(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
```

Verify that states are mapped to the good name, who is USA

Comment: I am binding my country only once in the if(!ispotback) if it so then even other countries wont populate their states right?? updated my question check once..

Comment: Chandra you can add AutoPostBack="true" on your DDL

Comment: Even it dint worked because as i can populate some states and i am unable to populate some other states,this is strange...

Comment: Ok i understand your position

Comment: What's country list who is not populated ?

Comment: USA,UK and srilanka and the country i am getting from the session value is southafrica

Comment: Verify the content of ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry(); debug this

Comment: There is no problem with ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry(); as all the countris are populating and you can check my XML i am having problem with some countries i dont know why it is happening like that.

Comment: your list contains these countries ????? var resul = ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry();

Comment: Yes my DDL1 contain these countries and the problem is i am unable to populate the states for some countries...

Comment: you have problem in your database, mapping problem, states are not good mapped to the country